# Static variable in a file scope

Tags: c++

I have used a static variable `"EnvVarIsSet"` in file scope in a certain `abc.cpp` file as follows

```
#include <env.h>
static bool EnvVarIsSet = IsEnvironmentVariableSet();
..
..
```

The routine `IsEnvironmentVariableSet()` is an extern routine and declared and defined in other files (`env.h & env.cpp`).
Somewhere down in the file `abc.cpp`, in some routine, I have used this variable (and also at other places in this file)

```
if( EnvVarIsSet )
{
   //do something
}
```

Does this mean, during runtime, whenever it encounters the variable `EnvVarIsSet` in `abc.cpp` file, `IsEnvironmentVariableSet()` routine will be called? Or does static variable as the one above will only work with constants (i.e. static binding, e.g. `const bool EnvVarIsSet = false`) ?

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
static bool EnvVarIsSet = IsEnvironmentVariableSet();
```

will be executed once in your compilation module. And every time the value of`EnvVarIsSet` will be the same.

Comment: Additionally, it will be executed at some unspecified time before `main()` is called. Other static initializer may have run, or they may not have run yet.

Comment: @Nik At compile time how will it know what IsEnvironmentVariableSet() would return? Wouldn't it be possible only at runtime?

Comment: @c45207 I tried using the static in two different cpp files belonging to two different libraries. In one of them it was called before main() and in the other, after I launched an application. Not sure, may be something to do with loading libraries on demand.